# Connect On-Premises Postgresql to Azure SQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm wondering if there's a way to have an on-premises PostgreSQL server that can be accessed in Azure the same way as an ordinary PostgreSQL server. So to have an endpoint in Azure with port 5432 and that endpoint would forward queries and requests to the on-premises database.

For example I need to keep data on-site but keep the access in Azure the same way through the same interface. We are trying to migrate our compute to Azure but need to keep all our data in house.

I've already looked into Data Factories and On-Premises Data Gateway but both seem to either be for migrating data or for access from App Services and other pre-defined Azure services.

We would be accessing from code.

**EDIT**: Clarified original question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you have an API layer, you can use that. Not sure what a "PostgreSQL interface" is - aside from talking directly to a PostgreSQL instance. And SQL Database isn't Postgres and provides no such emulation. I edited your tagging accordingly.

Comment: My bad, let me edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Its still not really clear what your trying to do here. However, I can confirm that its possible to access an on premises PostgreSQL instance using the Data Management Gateway in Azure Data Factory.

If you want to try it out I'd suggest using the copy wizard available from the Azure portal....

[image]

Go through the steps and create a simple pipeline.

The copy activity could then be scheduled to land your local data in an Azure SQL DB as frequently as 15mins if you wanted.

Hope this helps.